# How to create elements in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Doesn't vscode support creating element and DOM manipulations? I've read the [api referrence](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_window) but cannot figure out how to get the handle of document. I'm looking for something equivalent to `workspaceElement = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace)` in atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode does not expose the DOM, the only DOM manipulations that can be performed are through the [API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api) calls like decorations. Here is a sample of the decorator API in action https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample

The primary reason for not allowing direct manipulation of the DOM is to improve the speed and stability of the editor.